# J Language rank of power function

Tags: j

```
t=:1
test=: monad define
    t=.y
    t=. t, 0
)   
testloop=: monad def'test^:y t'
testloop 1
1 0
testloop 2
1 0 0
testloop 10
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In order to simplify this

```
(testloop 0),(testloop 1), (testloop 2), ...

110100100010000...
```

I tried

```
, testloop"0 (i.10)
```

but it gives

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0...
```

It seems like I have a problem with a rank, I can't figure out which one to use.
I would be grateful if you could help me on this issue. 
Thank you!

Comment: As bob has suggested below, this isn't a very natural approach to the problem in J. However if you are just using it as example to understand power (`^:`) then no problem and as bob has pointed out the issue is to do with padding of the results to make regular arrays. You need to box the intermediate results and then join them at the end. The following is not as elegant as bob's approach using `j.` but illustrates the general approach `([: ; <@(1 , 0 #~ ])"1 0) i.10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so much a rank problem as the fact that the results are padded with zeros so that the row lengths match.

```
   testloop 1
1 0
   testloop 2
1 0 0
   testloop"0 [ 1 2 
1 0 0
1 0 0
   testloop"0 [ 1 2 3
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

If I redefine your `test` and `testloop` to add a different appending digit, we can see how the padding is working.

```
   test2 =: 3 : 0
​t=. y
​t=. t,2
​)
   test2loop=: monad def'test2^:y t'
   test2loop"0 [1
1 2
   test2loop"0 [2
1 2 2
   test2loop"0 [ 1 2 NB. 0 padded in first row
1 2 0
1 2 2
   test2loop"0 [ 1 2 3  NB. 0's padded in first two rows
1 2 0 0
1 2 2 0
1 2 2 2
```

To get around the padding issue I will use `each=: &.>` so that the results are boxed before combining to avoid the padding.

```
   testloop each 1 2 3
+---+-----+-------+
|1 0|1 0 0|1 0 0 0|
+---+-----+-------+
   testloop each i. 10
+-+---+-----+-------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+
|1|1 0|1 0 0|1 0 0 0|1 0 0 0 0|1 0 0 0 0 0|1 0 0 0 0 0 0|1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
+-+---+-----+-------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

using `;` to unbox and ravel the results

```
   ; testloop each i. 10
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

To be honest I would be more inclined to use the fact that complex numbers used as the left argument of `#` introduce `0`'s for padding. The number of `0`'s depends on the imaginary value of the complex number.

```
   1j0 # 1
1
   1j1 # 1
1 0
   1j2 # 1
1 0 0
   test3=: monad def '(1 j. y)#1'
   test3 1
1 0
   test3 2
1 0 0
   test3 1 2
1 0 1 0 0
   test3 i. 10
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```